# How to give pattern in snowflake external table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have 2k files in S3 in a specific path (where only these files are present) with pattern emp_test_user_1.csv,emp_test_user_2.csv and so on.

Have to create an external table and load the data there. When I am trying to create and giving pattern like pattern='emp_test_user*.csv';

And loading the table, data is not getting loaded to it.
 Could you please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the pattern to match on the whole path, not just the filename.  For example:

`pattern='.*emp_test_user.*\\.csv'`.

The `.*` matches zero or more chars.  To match a dot you can use `[.]` or `\\.`.

---

UPDATE

You can test your pattern with LIST:

`list @mystage pattern='.*emp_test_user.*[.]csv'`